# Returning a JSON object from a PageMethod with custom formatting

Tags: asp.net, json, pagemethods

Is it possible to format how an object is returned as JSON from a PageMethod? ie. removing the first "d" element from the data, without writing the JSON from scratch.

**From:**
`{ "d": { "name": "bob", "email": "bob@example.com" } }`

**To**
`{ "name": "bob", email: "bob@example.com" }`

Comment: Do you have an example of your page logic?

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Microsoft's JSON serializer adds the d for some reason on the server side, and the client-side AJAX code that deserializes the JSON string expects it to be there.

Answer (score 4):

The extra `"d"` parameter is added by the .NET framework as an added security measure against XSS attacks [[source](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx)]. It's included when the `"Content-Type"` of the request specifies `"application/json"`.

I *think* you can get the framework to exclude it (ie don't wrap the result in the `"d"`) if you simply specifying the `"Content-Type"` of the request as something other than `"application/json"`. Try removing that header from the request (if you can) and seeing what .NET returns.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to use this content-type to return data as JSON, anything else just doesn't work. I think I need to look at this problem form another angle, ie. getting ExtJS to accept JSON in this format. Thanks.